# WATIR - not able to click on the link

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, watir, watir-webdriver

I have an HTML page which looks like this :

```
 <div>
      <div class="drawer">
         <div class="fill-layout">
            <div class="drawer-body">
               <div class="help-resources">
                  <div>
                    <ul class="help-resources-links">
                    <li><a href="/url1"><i class="book"></i>Book</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/url2"><i class="document"></i>Document</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/url3"><i class="form"></i>Form</a></li>
```

I want to click on

```
<li><a href="/url1"><i class="book"></i>Book</a></li>
```

and see if book was downloaded in the file path specified

My code looks like :

```
require 'watir'
prefs = {
  download: {
   prompt_for_download: true,
   default_directory: '/Users/user.name/Downloads/watir-downloads'
 }
}

browser = Watir::Browser.start 'https://admin:password@website.com'
```

I have tried few approaches but neither of them work

```
 1. browser.div(:class, "help-resources").link(:text, "Book").click

Output :
Traceback (most recent call last):
    10: from download.rb:18:in `<main>'
     9: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:125:in `click'
     8: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:657:in `element_call'
     7: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:661:in `rescue in element_call'
     6: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:661:in `count'
     5: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/element_collection.rb:29:in `each'
     4: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/element_collection.rb:70:in `to_a'
     3: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/element_collection.rb:124:in `elements'
     2: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:603:in `ensure_context'
     1: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:578:in `assert_exists'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:583:in `assert_element_found': 
unable to locate element: #<Watir::Div: located: false; {:class=>"help-resources", :tag_name=>"div"}> (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)

 2. browser.ul(:class, 'help-resources-links').child.a(:text, 'Book').click

Output :
assert_element_found': unable to locate element: #<Watir::UList: located: false; {:class=>"help-resources", :tag_name=>"ul"}> (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)

 3. if browser.div(:class, 'help-resources').child.a(:text, 'Book').exists?
        puts "in if block"
        browser.div(:class, 'help-resources'').a(:text, 'Book').click
    end
   Doesn't print "in if block" on terminal , code executes to completion
```

Comment: Simply try `b.link(text: 'Book').click`

Comment: @RAJ , code executes to completion but no file in the specified path

Comment: So link is being clicked now , right ?

Comment: you need  a selector to the main div where you have all the links and then you can loop to click each and retrieve any value you want

Comment: @neo7 what if you don't have a selector ?

Comment: sorry bro I am crazy busy will get back to tomorrow but always  should be selector such div, table etc ... also check the other way parse the table to Nokogiri  elements and then you can do magic :D